# Execute TX specific block.timestamp

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js

I have a smart contract with a function including

`require (block.timestamp > 1610406000)`

How can I execute a transaction in the correct block?

let's say a block is mined at 1610405998 -> this would fail

and then a block is mined at 1610406005 -> would succeed

How can I get in the block at 1610406005?
I'd like to know how I can get in the first valid block.

I tried already subscribing to new blocks, and sending transactions out based on a new block. But sometimes there are like 3 blocks in 3 seconds. I do use a node web3 script for this task.

Is there a possibility to know when the next block.timestamp is?

Comment: are you testing with a private blockchain? then mine it slower so blocks are more sparse. you can `SIGSTOP` the `geth` process with a bash script and then `SIGCONT` it after some time to create artificial pause

Comment: mining is based on the difficulty the lower the difficulty, the faster it mines blocks

Comment: you can modify `core/types/block.go` and insert a timestamp value in `Time` field of `types.Header` object just right after `Block` struct is created in the `NewBlock` function. For an example check Augur Project, they have their own `geth` node running with `fake time` option for testing. you would have to dig into it to find out what exactly did they modify to provide static timestamp all the time a block is created

Comment: maybe i didn't stated my question clear, I just took some random timestamps to illustrate it. I do it directly on eth mainnet.
My 2 questions are:
1. How can I include a transaction in a specific block based on their block.timestamp?
(sending transaction out via web3)
2. Is there a possibility to know when the next block.timestamp is? (on the mainnet)